# Git Merge only string.xml file

Tags: android, git, merge

New to git! We added Spanish to our product with two developers while the rest of the team went on to add other features. We put the Spanish version into our Development branch and now need to merge in the changes in for everyone else. I wanted to just merge the string tables first and do the rest of the merge in small chunks instead of trying to do it all at once.

I tried:

```
git checkout develop
git merge OtherBranch res\values\strings.xml
```

and got the result:

```
merge: res\values\strings.xml - not something we can merge
```

Thanks in advance. I know this would just merge my English strings.xml but I should be able to figure it out from here, once I know what I was doing wrong.

Comment: There is `git merge-file`. Take a look at it (`git help merge-file`)

Comment: I do not need a three way merge. I just need to merge the string file in our main develop repository with the one the rest of my team is working on. Instead of merging a repository I just want to merge one file in the repository out of 200 that have changed. I have read 10 articles and blogs and none talk about merging one file of a repository. Is it so simple it is not worth writing about or so complex no one has figured it out or so unusual it is a far corner case? It seems this would need to be done by people everyday.

Comment: It sounds like you want to jump in with a lot of assumptions on how git gets stuff done. Ah, no... _normally_ you don't merge single files.. you merge separate _branches_ with whatever changes are needed from all of them. The case _does_ exist for, every once in a while, requiring to only merge stuff on a single file while not touching anything else (hence `git merge-file`), but it's not something that happens very often.

Comment: Great points. There are 200 files added or changed, 60-70 of them need intervention and about 100 merged clean. To tackle the whole thing will take weeks while the branch changes under me. Huge room for error. I was hoping to merge fragment by fragment (Android) in small pieces. Is there a better way to do that? Am I making it too hard?

Comment: well.... nothing to get you out of your current situation..... just, for the future, merge (or rebase) more often so that you don't have to go through an excruciating merge process.

Answer (score 0):

If the file was never modified on `develop`, you can simply take the version from `OtherBranch` :

```sh
git checkout develop
git checkout OtherBranch -- res\values\strings.xml
# check your 'git status', and 'git diff --cached' to review the file
# if all is ok :
git commit
```

*note* : this does not *merge* the contents, it completely overwrites the content of `strings.xml` on `develop` with the content that is stored in `OtherBranch`.

---

If you need to actually *merge* the file -- eg : changes that were brought to `strings.xml` on branch `develop` while otehr people worked on `OtherBranch` -- you can create a branch which only has the modifications brought to `strings.xml` :

```sh
git checkout OtherBranch
git log -1  # write down the commit ID of current commit

# here is the fork point of develop and OtherBranch :
git merge-base develop OtherBranch
git checkout -b Translations [commit id of fork point]  # give whatever name you want to this branch
git checkout OtherBranch -- res\values\strings.xml
git commit  # just to have a reference somewhere : mention in this commit message
            # that this version comes from OtherBranch, with the commit id you saw
            # at line 2.

# you can now merge Translations into develop :
git checkout develop
git merge Translations

# or cherry-pick the single commit from Translations :
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick Translations
```